# What is the difference between an array and range as it pertains to WorksheetFunctions

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I am trying to use two worksheet functions within a sub, and for `WorksheetFunction.PercentRank`, I can use the `relevant_array`, however I keep getting an error when I use `relevant_array` for `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`.  I want to get that same array/range to work in `.CountIf` as is in `.PercentRank`.

```
Dim y As Variant
Dim z As Variant
        PricePerKG = POCost
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Modified Item Extract")
        Set relevant_Array = ws.Range(ws.Range("B2"), ws.Range("B2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        y = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(relevant_Array, POCost, 4)
        Percentile = Format(y, "0.00%")

        z = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(relevant_Array, ">" & POCost)
        PriceAbove = z
```

Comment: You've called it `relevant.Array` in the second call instead of `relevant_Array`...

Comment: @Dave thanks for the correction.  That was merely a transposition error on my part, I still get the  error when I correct it.

Comment: WorksheetFunction.PercentRank takes a double as it's second aurgument.  You should declase POCost as Double